# json-server - strange autoincrement id

Tags: javascript, node.js, json-server

I've got a problem with id-autoincrementation on my json-server. I set up a simple default json-server with single db.json file to watch.

Here is my db.json file (simple generated data):

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Lucy",
      "last_name": "Ballmer",
      "email": "lucyb56@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "first_name": "Anna",
      "last_name": "Smith",
      "email": "annasmith23@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "first_name": "Robert",
      "last_name": "Brown",
      "email": "bobbrown432@yahoo.com"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "first_name": "Roger",
      "last_name": "Bacon",
      "email": "rogerbacon12@yahoo.com"
    },
  ]
}
```

Now I'm trying to POST some data to db.json using Postman.
I have configured endpoint:

```
http://localhost:4040/users
```

And I'm doing POST with following data:

```
{
  "first_name": "Marian",
  "last_name": "Gowno3333",
  "email": "gowno@gmail.com"
}
```

Json-server increments IDs automatically by default, but as a result I get strange id format like so:

```
"id": "8OZrQkH"
```

Instead of getting for example "id": 6.

Why is this happening? Is there any option to set IDs format as 1, 2, 3 etc.?

Comment: Is this issue fixed for you? How? Please update your answer if you have...

Answer (score 12):

The last record's id type is `string`: `"5"`, so the server generate a random string for next id. Just make it number to fix.

Comment: Got it.. Instead of this.. id:"5" -- > id:5

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but even when I turn the id to a number, it still generates a random string id.
Then I have found that in another application, this problem didn't happen. The difference between them: the json-server version. So after I downgraded from "1.0.0-alpha.23" to "^0.17.4", the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

you must value id be number not string

```
{
  "id": "5", ==> "id" : 5
  "first_name": "Roger",
  "last_name": "Bacon",
  "email": "rogerbacon12@yahoo.com"
},
```